# How to test result of resolved setTimeout function in Jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, jestjs

I have const with function and let that have result of resolving

```
let timeoutResult = null;

const timeoutCall = () =>
    setTimeout(() =>
        (timeoutResult = "finished"), 1);
```

I was trying such method

```
jest.useFakeTimers();
it('async timeout', () => {
    timeoutCall();
    jest.runAllTimers();

    expect(timeoutResult).toBe("finished");
})
```

But it doesnt work. I don't understand why?

How to make test in Jest for `timeoutResult = finished` is `true`

Comment: You cannot use `async`/`await` here since the code is not promise-based.

Comment: Just wait longer than that 1ms, do your check, finish the test? Please show us your attempt.

Comment: I uses ```setTimeout``` method and then ```expect```. This method is working and test passes, but this is not right way I want. I need somehow check when ```seTtimeout``` execute and then ```expect```.

Comment: I just mind that I can use ```setInterval``` to check status of ```timeoutResult``` every 1ms

Comment: Sure you could use polling, but in either case you'll need a time limit on how long you want to wait for the value to change. Better solution would obviously to change `timeoutCall` so that it notifies the caller of finishing…

Comment: I understand that is better to make ```timeoutCall``` in promise and so on. But in my case I can't change ```timeoutCall```. So I need a solution.
P.S. ```setInterval``` is not an option. Is there a way to make Jest check ```timeoutResult``` every ```n``` sec until it will be ```true```?

Comment: Why do you think `setInterval` is not an option?

Comment: It always make ```true```. Doesnt matter what interval will be in ```setInterval``` and ```setTimeout```
examp. ```const timeoutCall = () => setTimeout(() => (timeoutResult = "finished"), 20);```  Test  ```it('async timeout', () => { timeoutCall(); setInterval( () => { expect(timeoutResult).toBe('finished');}, 1); })```

Comment: You need to make your entire test asynchronous (i.e. call `done` when finished). And yes, with an interval of `1` the first callback will be executed after the `timeoutCall`. (Btw if you want to post code, better [edit] your question to include it with formatting)

Comment: I'm not so advanced in Jest. Can you please give a sample?

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#callbacks